# Read csv file where values of one variable are expanding to multiple line for each observation in R

Tags: r, csv, parsing

The structure of my raw csv file or txt file is:

```
Name Description Salary Period
Anna  motivated   1000    10
       driven
      easygoing
Bob     nice        800     10
        nett
Dan     lazy        1600    23
Anna   charming    1600     20
        harsh
```

I would like to read the data into R and shows as:

```
Anna  motivated,driven,easygoing   1000    10
```

So each person is one observation.

Comment: Can you please create a reproducible sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `csv` is as in the Note at the end we create a grouping variable using `cumsum(!is.na(csv$Name))`.  (You may need to replace `!is.na(csv$Name)` with some other condition if the empty spots in Name are not NAs; however, without a reproducible example in the question we have no way ot determining that.). We then apply `toString` to `Name` by group and use `na.omit` to remove rows that contain NAs in the original data.  If the empty spots are not NAs then `na.omit` will need to be modified appropriately. No packages are used.

```
transform(na.omit(csv), 
  Description = tapply(csv$Description, cumsum(!is.na(csv$Name)), toString))
```

giving:

```
  Name                  Description Salary Period
1 Anna motivated, driven, easygoing   1000     10
4  Bob                   nice, nett    800     10
6  Dan                         lazy   1600     23
7 Anna              charming, harsh   1600     20
```

### Note

The `csv` data frame in reproducible form as used in this answer:

```
csv <- structure(list(Name = c("Anna", NA, NA, "Bob", NA, "Dan", "Anna", 
  NA), Description = c("motivated", "driven", "easygoing", "nice", 
  "nett", "lazy", "charming", "harsh"), Salary = c(1000L, NA, NA, 
  800L, NA, 1600L, 1600L, NA), Period = c(10L, NA, NA, 10L, NA, 
  23L, 20L, NA)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
  "8"), class = "data.frame")
```

This looks like this with NAs in the empty spots.

```
> csv
  Name Description Salary Period
1 Anna   motivated   1000     10
2 <NA>      driven     NA     NA
3 <NA>   easygoing     NA     NA
4  Bob        nice    800     10
5 <NA>        nett     NA     NA
6  Dan        lazy   1600     23
7 Anna    charming   1600     20
8 <NA>       harsh     NA     NA
```